# Where to get rate of change for calculating ephemeris from JPL Horizons

Tags: ephemeris

I have a working implementation of [Schlyter's method](http://www.stjarnhimlen.se/comp/tutorial.html) for calculating the Sun's position.   I would like to know how Schlyter got the 3.24587E-5_deg in the following calculation for Mercury.

```
N =  48.3313_deg + 3.24587E-5_deg   * d    (Long of asc. node)
```

I could not find this number in JPL Horizons.   I'm guessing it's the difference between the N at two epochs divided by number of days between the two epochs, but I'm not sure.

Comment: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/txt/p_elem_t1.txt doesn't answer your question, and actually disagrees with your equation. https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/txt/p_elem_t2.txt gives the same information with slightly different coordinates, but still shows the change in Mercury's ascending node as being negative, not positive.

Comment: @barrycarter Schlyter in that article used a date before 2000 as the observation date.  Could that be why the sign is different?   Also, if I took 0.12534081 deg/Cy from your rate tables divided by the avg no. of days in a century (3650.2425), I get 3.4338E-5.   Not quite 3.24E-5, but close.   Any idea how to get deg/Cy from JPL Horizons for any object in its catalog?

Comment: I don't know if there's a uniform way to get this from HORIZONS, or even if osculating elements for other bodies precess at a uniform rate. As you suggested, you could use HORIZONS (or SPICE) to simply compute the osculating elements at constant intervals and draw a best fit linear regression line through them. As VSOP2013 theory notes, you might even want to find polynomial fits: https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/ASTRO/VSOP2013-secular.dat (sorry, the only copy I have is my own).

Comment: I'm sure you're aware of https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi but this only yields fixed osculating elements, and doesn't include a precession term. Even pages like https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/joviansatfact.html give only fixed elements.

Comment: @barrycarter thanks.   If you repost the above as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Working on a better answer, stay tuned!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My email to Paul Schlyter and his reply, posted with permission:

> On http://www.stjarnhimlen.se/comp/tutorial.html you note that
>   Mercury's ascending node is given as:
>
> N =  48.3313_deg + 3.24587E-5_deg   * d
>
> According to https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/txt/p_elem_t1.txt Mercury's
>   ascending node precesses in the negative direction.
>
> As [Where to get rate of change for calculating ephemeris from JPL Horizons](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/25362) notes, NASA's
>   value matches the negative of your value almost exactly.
>
> Are you using a different sign convention here, or is this an error?

Reply:

> It's neither - instead I use a somewhat different reference system.
>
> I use the "epoch of the day" instead of the fixed epoch of, say,
>   J2000.0. So add the rate of precession to the negative rate of change
>   you found at NASA's site, and you should get my rate of change.
>
> Since I use the "epoch of the day", the positions I get are suitable
>   to compute e.g. the rise, transit, and set times for the planets. Of
>   course they are also good for computing the positions of several
>   planets relative to one another. But if you need the positions to plot
>   on a star map drawn for some fixed epoch, you need to apply a
>   correction for precession to these positions.
>
> Yes, it can be confusing to distinguish those different astronomical
>   coordinate systems from one another. But that's a consequence of
>   living on the planet Earth which orbits the Sun, rotates, and wobbles.